# Apply a discount using VueJS and Laravel

Tags: javascript, laravel, laravel-5.1, vue.js

I haven't gone down the road of creating custom components, I have got it checking for the coupon code now I need to know how I can set a the cost then apply the discount.

Heres the JS I have currently

```
new Vue({
el: '#coupons',

data: function() {
    return {
        coupon: {
            code: '',
            description: '',
            discount: 0
        },

        valid: false
    };
},

methods: {
    validate: function() {
        this.$http.get('/coupons/' + this.coupon.code)
            .success(function(coupon) {
                this.coupon = coupon;
                this.valid = true;
                this.coupon.description = 'Great! You entered a valid coupon.';

            })
            .error(function() {
                this.coupon.code = '';
                this.coupon.description = 'Sorry, that coupon does not exist.';
            });
    }
}
});
```

Anyone advise on how to achieve this based on the above please :) Presumably I would need to pass the value from Laravel to the JS, again how would I achieve this, then apply the discount, would I se v-model for example to use two way binding?

Comment: Are you getting any erro or something? I guess I don't understand quite well your problem. And also, after a get call, the result is in `response.data` not just `response`

Comment: No errors @YerkoPalma just not sure how I can make the discount be applied to the price on screen,

Comment: Then you should also specify the format of the data returned by your `/coupons/:code` action. Some things to note: 1) Whatever you are returning is in `coupon.data` not directly in `coupon`. 2)Make sure you are using the `v-resource` plugin with `Vue.use()` 3) also make sure that your route is fine, and that the server isn't specting any extension like `.json`  for instance

Comment: @YerkoPalma everything returns has expected, but I'm unsure on how to firstly set the 'cost' from Laravel to the JS. Then discount the coupon number from the cost and then display on screen.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

why not echo the price into a javascript object?

```
(function(globals){
   globals.price = {{ $somePrice }};
})(window.globals || (window.globals ={}));
```

then share the state with your vuejs component,

```
new Vue({
   data:{
      coupon: {
        code: '',
        description: '',
        discount: 0
      },
      valid: false,
      price: window.globals.price
   }
});
```

You can trigger the validation via several events depending on your choice;
say for example you want to fire the ajax request when the user stops entering on the input

then you can go `<input v-model="coupon.code" type="text" @keyup="validate() | debounce 1000">`

the code above will call the method validate a second after the last keyup

now for the validate function

```
...
    validate: function() {
        // assign this to another variable to make it accessible in the promise scope
        var _this = this;
        this.$http.get('/coupons/' + this.coupon.code).then(function(response) {
             // you can just pass a negative response  (false or null)from laravel
             if (response) {
                  _this.coupon = response;

             }

        });

    }
```

finally you can use vuejs' computed property to update the display of the discounted amount.

```
computed: {
    discounted: function() {
        return this.price - this.coupon.discount;
    }
}
```

and in the view

```
<span>{{ discounted }}</span>
```

you should still pass the coupon to the backend and recalculate the discounted price from there when the user buys or whatever he does.

Sources: 
http://vuejs.org/guide/events.html
http://vuejs.org/guide/computed.html